# Zend_XmlRpc parameter trouble

Tags: zend-framework, xml-rpc, zend-xmlrpc

I'm trying to get a simple client/server XMLRPC server setup but I am having trouble using parameters. The code runs fine if I take the **$client_id** parameter out of the **fetchClient()** method and **$client->call()**. However if I include it, the server returns "**Calling parameters do not match signature**"

Controller Code:

```
class XmlrpcController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Server();
        $server->setClass('App_Service_Customer','customer');
        echo $server->handle();
    }
}
```

App/Service/Customer.php:

```
class App_Service_Customer
{
    /**
     * @param int $client_id
     * @return string
     */
    public function fetchCustomer($client_id)
    {
        return 'john doe';
    }
}
```

Client Testing Code:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://localhost/xmlrpc');
echo $client->call('customer.fetchCustomer', 1);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregard. I figured out the correct parameter to input:

```
echo $client->call('customer.fetchCustomer', array(array('client_id' => 1)));
```